# Oncomplete of Primefaces component fileUpload is never called

Tags: jsf, file-upload, primefaces

I have a form upload component on my page and want to make more actions in JavaScript after file upload is complete and page updated.

I put simple log statement to test for "oncomplete" execution, but it never happens.
File is successfully uploaded and other parts of page updated, but no "oncomplete" actions performed.
Here is my component:

```
<p:fileUpload id="objectUpload1"
                fileUploadListener="#{importBackingBean.handleFileUpload}"
                mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"
                invalidFileMessage="Недопустимый тип файла"
                invalidSizeMessage="Размер файла превышает 5 МВ"
                cancelLabel="#{msg['stop_LABEL']}"
                uploadLabel="#{msg['Upload_LABEL']}"
                label="#{msg['Choose_LABEL']}" update="results objects_Data"
                sizeLimit="5000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xlsx|xls)$/"
                oncomplete="load();" />
```

And my Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                function load() {
                    console.log('File Uploaded!');
                    $("button[id*='load']").click();
                }                       
</script>
```

Button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Загрузить полисы"                   
                oncomplete="#{importModelBean.needToLoadMore ? 'load();' :'none();'}"
                id="load"
                action="#{importBackingBean.loadOneRow(importModelBean.current)}"
                process="@this" update="mainViewForm:objects_Data" />
```

When I click the button manually it works just fine. But not getting clicked with oncomplete of filepload.

Comment: I have no documentation at hand, but are you sure `oncomplete` is supported like this?

Comment: @Kukeltje - yes, oncomplete is supported for fileUpload in Primefaces. Here is the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/4.0/primefaces-p/fileUpload.html)

Comment: I kniw where the documentation is ;-) juat not goung to access a several MB large file on my mobile phone... will check later at home

Answer (score 1):

Using the codes given, I have reproduced this scenario. Although `$("button[id*='load']").click();` has been invoked correctly, no log is showing. I am guessing that the button with an id `load` is set to `ajax=”false”`. If this is true, then I think that the message was logged the moment `console.log('File Uploaded!');` is invoked but was cleared since the page is updated after the load button process. Do you need the log for something? If not, just remove `console.log('File Uploaded!');` code and it should work just fine.

**EDIT:**

I misunderstood you. I thought that your concern was that the message was not logged in the console.

I have tested your codes on two projects (running on two different computers) and I can’t reproduce your problem.

Project 1:
Primefaces 6.0
JSF 2.0
WAS 8.5
IE 11

Project 2:
Primefaces 5.x
JSF 2.0
Glassfish 4.1
Google Chrome

I even tried `oncomplete=”alert(‘hello!’)”` and it worked fine.

I think that the problem is somewhere else.
For the mean time, can you try the following codes and see if it works:

```
<p:fileUpload id="objectUpload1"
                fileUploadListener="#{importBackingBean.handleFileUpload}"
                mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true"
                invalidFileMessage="Недопустимый тип файла"
                invalidSizeMessage="Размер файла превышает 5 МВ"
                cancelLabel="#{msg['stop_LABEL']}"
                uploadLabel="#{msg['Upload_LABEL']}"
                label="#{msg['Choose_LABEL']}" update="results objects_Data"
                sizeLimit="5000000" allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(xlsx|xls)$/"
                oncomplete="rc()" />

<p:remoteCommand name="rc"                
                oncomplete="#{importModelBean.needToLoadMore ? 'load();' :'none();'}"
                action="#{importBackingBean.loadOneRow(importModelBean.current)}"
                process="@this" update="mainViewForm:objects_Data" />
```

For more information about `p:remoteCommand`, please refer to primefaces showcase [RemoteCommand](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/remoteCommand.xhtml).

Comment: only two blocks are updated(results and objects_Data) after file upload, not the whole page. Button is p:commandButton - so Ajax is true by default and I dont't set it to false(code example updated). Button works if I click it manually, but not with oncomplete.

Comment: My comment was too long so I edited my previous answer. Please see EDIT: part.